# Не могу выбрать JSON-элемент по наименованию

Tags: javascript, json

```
           xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                // если запрос принят и сервер ответил, что всё в порядке
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    // выводим 5-минутный токен из ответа 
                    let refreshToken = this.responseText['accessToken']
                    result.innerHTML = refreshToken;
                }
            };
```

Ответ - объект в формате JSON:

```
{"type":"Bearer","accessToken":"...","refreshToken":"..."}
```

Попытка вывести accessToken:

```
undefined
```

Comment: А `this.responseText`  откуда берётся? разве не должно быть `xhr.responseText` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью `JSON.parse` трансформируйте JSON в объект JavaScript, а после получите нужное вам значение:

```
let refreshToken = JSON.parse(this.responseText).accessToken;
```